# Ubuntu 20.04 application search bar missing

Tags: gnome-shell, 20.04, activities-overview

After updating to Ubuntu 19.10, pressing the <kbd>Super</kbd> button only shows the list of the currently opened applications. It does not show the applications list when nothing is opened.

Also, the search bar is missing and I need to search the applications manually from the top bar.

My current Ubuntu version is 20.04 LTS and `gnome-shell` version is 3.36.1 and the problem still persists.

The image below is what I see on pressing the super button.

[image: screenshot of the problem]

Comment: First, try creating a new account to see if the issue may be due to your current user profile.